# Can a Hibernation file be restored and if so, how

Tags: windows-vista, crash, hibernate

My system crashed, and when I started back up, my hibernation file was gone. Now this is a problem as I was about to make a complete partition copy and needed what was also stored in that to analyze a issue with my system. Now I know the whole CMD, turn hibernation on bit, but what I want to know is, is there anyway to restore the exact lost .sys file and if there is a way, how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How much have you used your system since the data loss? Regardless, even though there are lots of free and paid data recovery utilities on offer, I *highly* doubt you'll be able to perform a perfect 100% recovery of the entire hiberfil.sys file.

Comment: Any recommendations on what ones to use.

Comment: You can try [this one](http://www.r-studio.com) and [this](http://www.piriform.com/recuva), but there are many more (perhaps some that are even better).